# Django server on Digital Ocean connection reset by peer

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm trying to set up a django server on my digital ocean instance with Django 2.0.4 and a Ubuntu 16.0.4 droplet. I ssh into the droplet as root and start the server with

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

And the django server would start up fine. But a few seconds later without me doing anything, these errors would come up repeatedly:

```
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('175.100.8.37', 12774)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/root/website/back-end/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('175.100.8.37', 12775)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/root/website/back-end/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

This is my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "tedxuwa.com",
    "www.tedxuwa.com",
    "localhost:8000"
]
```

`DEBUG` is set to False and I'm definitely not the one making these requests. Why would these errors been happening?

Comment: Either the IP address you have was being used for something else in the past or someone is scanning the server for vulnerabilities. Either set up a firewall or try getting a new droplet with a new IP address.

Comment: Hi @Haiz I am facing same issue, do you have any solution of this problem.

Comment: @VikramSinghChandel I ended up removing that droplet and creating a new one and that seems to fix it. I also started running Django off of Nginx instead of using the built-in development server

Comment: All our DigitalOcean servers are constantly being scanned for vulnerabilities. Interestingly it's scanning only php type exploits. Hmmm, nice way for DO to earn more on traffic based pricing ) 6-20Kb/sec 24 times a day :) 

So how do we disable this from console log?